# Gecko/Firefox 33.0 crashes on YouTube IFrame API ytPlayer.seekTo(seconds, allowSeekAhead)

Tags: javascript, firefox, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api, slimerjs

I do have serious issues with the youtube api. ytPlayer.seekTo() method crashes under Firefox 33.0 (used through desktop as well as slimerjs). It crashes on both firefox (full-installation) as well as xulrunner. Any ideas what may be the reason for this and how to solve it?

Error: Default Windows Error Promt: XULRunner stopped working The programm was closed in reaseon of an problem. You ll be notified as soon as an solution is available.

[image: XULRunner stopped working]

Shell Errors (Number in square brakets varii from execution to execution somehow random:

```
[6064] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/rel-m-rel-xr_w32_bld-000000000/build/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 1547
[12464] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/rel-m-rel-xr_w32_bld-000000000/build/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 1547
```

The code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0">
<script>
var ytPlayer;
var nextPlayerTime = 0
// on api ready
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    console.log("youtube iframe api ready");
    ytPlayer = new YT.Player("youTubePlayer", {
        events: {
            onStateChange: function(e) {
                if (e.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                    console.log("youtube playing go to next");
                    ytPlayer.pauseVideo();
                    nextPlayerTime +=10;
                    ytPlayer.seekTo( nextPlayerTime ,true );
                    ytPlayer.playVideo();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>

<iframe id="youTubePlayer" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hKWmFWRVLlU?version=3&vq=hd1080&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&allowscriptaccess=always&wmode=opaque&autoplay=1" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: 0px;"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you describe what you mean by "crashes"; more specifically, what do you expect this code to do, and what is it doing instead? As I read the code, it looks designed to jump ahead every 1 seconds each time it fires a PLAYING event ... and since the YouTube fires a PLAYING event whenever it resumes from a seek, this code ought to just jump super quickly through the whole video in 10 second increment frame shots. And that's exactly what it is doing on Firefox, Chrome, Safari, every browser I've tried. Are you expecting something else? Or are you seeing some other result?

Comment: @jilmcdonald, for me its crashing on windows